# Set space between divs

Tags: css

I have two divs like this:

```
<section id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="left" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="right" runat="server" />
  </div>
</section>
```

And here is my css:

```
#left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 17px;    
}

#right {
  float: right;
}
```

I want the space between the divs to be `40px`. I tried adding padding, margin and width in my css, but I think it didn't set the padding to correct `40px`. How to do it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Float them both the same way and add the margin of 40px. If you have 2 elements floating opposite ways you will have much less control and the containing element will determine how far apart they are.

```
#left{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
#right{
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 64):

For folks searching for solution to set spacing between `N` divs, here is another approach using pseudo selectors:

```
div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

You can also combine child pseudo selectors:

```
div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution for spacing between N divs can be:

```css
div + div {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

We are leveraging `+` css selector. It only selects the `<div>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.

> Notice: we are setting `margin-left` not `margin-right` here.

Answer (score 2):

You need a gutter between two div gutter can be made as following

```
margin(gutter) = width - gutter size
E.g margin = calc(70% - 2em)
```

```css
    body{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    
    #main div{
        float: left;
        background-color:#ffffff;
        width: calc(50% - 1.5em);
        margin-left: 1.5em;
    }
```

```html
    <body bgcolor="gray">
    <section id="main">
            <div id="left">
                Something here     
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                    Someone there
            </div>
    </section>
    </body>
```